SST(Serverless Stack) : Migration from the V2 to V3.3.21
SST (Serverless Stack) is an open-source framework developed by Anomaly Innovations that helps you build and deploy serverless applications on AWS. It offers several features and tools to make developing serverless applications easier and more efficient.
I am migrating from the  V2 to V3.3.21 so this is my sst.config.ts
import { SSTConfig } from "sst";
import { MyStack } from "./stack/MyStack";

export default {
  config(_input) {
    return {
      name: "app",
      region: "us-east-1",
    };
  },
  stacks(app) {
    app.setDefaultFunctionProps({
      runtime: "nodejs20.x",//runtime for the generated functions to ss
    });

    app.addDefaultFunctionPermissions("*");//lambda functions permissions

    app.stack(MyStack);
    // app.stack(Dynamo);
  },
} satisfies SSTConfig;

and I wish to know where is the SSTConfig gone? Or what is the replacement for it? Thank you for your help. I've searched for the whole web, but this version is recent (at the moment I write this post), so I found any docs about the migration from V2.x to V3.3.21
